# Change innerHTML when audio is playing or paused

Tags: javascript, audio, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I'm trying to change text inside of several buttons when audio is paused. For now my function does pause and play the audio, but for a reason I don't quite understand, my function won't change the HTML inside buttons.

⚆ _ ⚆ What am I doing wrong?

```js
  var Audio = document.getElementById('Audio');
  var buttonPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.music-play-button');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonPlay.length; i++) {
    buttonPlay[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      if (Audio.paused) {
        Audio.play();
        buttonPlay[i].innerHTML = "Pause Music";
      } else {
        Audio.pause();
        buttonPlay[i].innerHTML = "Play Music";
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<audio id="Audio" src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0xu2nln4mpathtw/The%20Wraith.mp3'></audio>
```

**UPDATE:**
here is an improved version based on [Kevin Mpofu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778667/17286440) solution.
It does change HTML inside all buttons when audio is paused or played.

```js
      var Audio = document.getElementById("Audio");
      var buttonPlay = document.querySelectorAll(".music-play-button");

        
      buttonPlay.forEach((prm) => {
        Audio.addEventListener('playing', (event) => {prm.innerHTML = "Pause Music";})});

      buttonPlay.forEach((prm) => {
        Audio.addEventListener('pause', (event) => {prm.innerHTML = "Play Music";})});

      buttonPlay.forEach((prm) => {
        prm.addEventListener("click", function () {
          if (Audio.paused) {
            Audio.play();
            prm.innerHTML = "Pause Music";
          } else {
            Audio.pause();
            prm.innerHTML = "Play Music";
          }
        });
      });
```

```html
    <button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
    <button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
    <button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
    <audio id="Audio" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0xu2nln4mpathtw/The%20Wraith.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var Audio = document.getElementById('Audio');
var buttonPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.music-play-button');


buttonPlay.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (Audio.paused) {
          Audio.play();
          btn.innerHTML = "Pause Music";
        } else {
          Audio.pause();
          btn.innerHTML = "Play Music";
        }
      }); 
});
```

```html
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<button class="music-play-button">Play Music</button>
<audio id="Audio" src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0xu2nln4mpathtw/The%20Wraith.mp3'></audio>
```